# Destroy method in rails and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, mongoid

I am trying to delete a particular "work" from an array of "works" which is embedded in user.

In my work.html.erb file in **views**:-

```
<% @works.each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', profiles_destroy_path(f), data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

And in my **controller**:-

```
def destroy
@work = current_user.works.find(params[:id])
@work.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_url }
end
end
```

I am getting following error:-

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind at /profiles/destroy.56fa4d2f498b5908a002e2e8
```

P.S. - I am new to rails.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `params[:id`] is not `nil`. There's no :id at session start and you get the `Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind` exception above.

Answer (score 0):

delete action doesn't have path by default..

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', profiles_path(f), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :delete %>
```

That will call the destroy action from your controller.

And make sure params[:id] is not nil.

PS: use rails 4 annotation (avoid using rockets (=>))

Comment: rails 4 annotation? Also, there's nothing wrong with hashrockets.

Comment: ups sorry, yeah it is not rails4, it is from ruby core. it has nothing wrong but for me adds unnecessary verbosity. @SergioTulentsev :)

Comment: @JuanManuelRodulfoSalcedo it shows params[:id] is nil. can you tell me how to resolve this. Do i need to write something in routes.rb file.

Comment: make sure "@works" has persisted objects, looks like you are iterating over a collection of unsaved or invalid objects and they haven't been persisted in the db (that is why suppose they have no id) @KumarDeepak

Answer (score 0):

There may be an error in Juan's answer.

I believe you want:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', profile_path(f), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Note: the singular "profile_path" instead of "profiles_path"

This is because the destroy action uses the same path as the show action, but uses a DELETE method instead of a GET.  (Which you can observe by running "rake routes" in your terminal and comparing the two routes.)